# sync mongodb with elasticsearch scala environment

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Im using reactive mongo as my mongodb(v3.4) driver in my play 2.6 application.

Does someone have a recommended way to sync every insert/update I have with my elasticsearch(v5.6)?

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: @cchantep i didnt try, im looking for ways to do so online but cant find a tool for play environment...the only thing i found is mongo-connector but it looks like its for python env

Comment: So first try and then SO can be used to ask questions.

Comment: @cchantep thank for the help, your the best :)